# Multiple column join in linq

Tags: linq

I want to convert this sql query to linq

```
SELECT Students.StdId, Mark.Value
FROM Departments INNER JOIN
Mark ON Departments.DepId = Mark.DepId INNER JOIN
Students ON Departments.DepId = Students.DepId AND Mark.StdId = Students.StdId
```

I did this, but it's wont working

```
from s in Students
join d in Departments on s.DepId equals d.DepId
join m in Marks on new {s.StdId, d.DepId} equals new {m.StdId, m.DepId}
select new{
  SId=s.StdId,
  Value=m.Value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try with

```
from s in Students
join d in Departments on s.DepId equals d.DepId
join m in Marks 
on new {StdId = s.StdId, DepId = d.DepId} equals new {StdId = m.StdId, DepId= m.DepId}
select new{
  SId=s.StdId,
  Value=m.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from s in Students
join m in Marks on s.StdId equals m.StdId
join d in Departments on m.DepId equals d.DepId
select new { s.StdId, m.Value };
```